# Mobile multiplatform app in windows 7 os and with visual studio 2012

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created website in visual studio 2012 for mobile and in android studio I have created web view to call my website ...android studio creates android file for android phone . now similarly I want to create windows and apple phone applications. 
is there any software or method through which I can convert my android file to windows and apple compatible phone? 
do I need to have mac and windows 8 operating systems for creating web view ??

Answer (score 0):

For your case you may checkout [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) , [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) or [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)

These are the best option for cross platform development

Comment: thanks ..actually I have installed Xamarin..but for developing ios application it requires to connect to MAC for compilation and for windows phone application it requires windows 8 operating system...Is there any other way to create windows and ios executable files?

Comment: unfortunately no..in order to compile for IOS you need a mac